# What is wrong with my jQuery animate method?

Tags: jquery, html

I am simply making an image to animate from left to right and from right to left? Why this is not working? I did this with a paragraph it moved perfectly. But with an image it's not working!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("img").animate({left:"100px"}, 'slow');
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("img").animate({left:"0"}, 'slow');
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn1">Animate</button>
<button class="btn2">Reset</button>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting left and top properties won't work unless the image has position.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9pfY7/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position` for your images:

```
img {
    position: relative; /* or position: absolute */
}
```

so that the `left` property can work.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8QU7c/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the image style position:absolute

```
<img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" style="position:absolute"/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pNM6/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `img` in `absolute` position:

```
<img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" style="position: absolute" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
<img src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" style="position: relative; left: 0" />
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9pfY7/1/)**